# Line Code break " _" in StarBasic Macros of LibreCalc do not work in quoted string

Tags: libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

Line Code break " _" in StarBasic Macros of LibreCalc do not work in quoted string

So how i can escape in quotes line-continuation character " _"?

eg.

```
Const SCells = "B17:C28,E17:G28,L17:O28,T17:V28,AA17:AE28,AN17:AR28, _
BB17:BD28,BO17:BS28,BY17:CB28,CG17:CI28,CS17:CW28,DB17:DF28,DL17:DN28, _
DU17:DX28,EF17:EK28,ET17:EV28,FA17:FD28,FJ17:FL28,FV17:FZ28,GD17:GF28, _
GM17:GO28"
splitCells = Split(SCells,",")

sub Cells_range

for i = 0 to 2 step 1

print splitCells(i)

next i

end sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, correct syntactic is

```
Const SCells = "B17:C28,E17:G28,L17:O28,T17:V28,AA17:AE28,AN17:AR28," & _
    "BB17:BD28,BO17:BS28,BY17:CB28,CG17:CI28,CS17:CW28,DB17:DF28,DL17:DN28," & _
    "DU17:DX28,EF17:EK28,ET17:EV28,FA17:FD28,FJ17:FL28,FV17:FZ28,GD17:GF28," & _
    "GM17:GO28"

Sub  Cells_range
    splitCells = Split(SCells,","), etc.
```

Pay attention - the calculation of `splitCells = ...` is written inside the procedure

Answer (score 0):

I found that in Strings in starbasic Macros in LibreCalc:

- you must end the quotes then
- break the line with the line-continuation starbasic / vba space-underscore character " _"
- and then use "&" which join strings
- all broken strings must be in quotes in their beginning and in their ends.

e.g.

```
Const SCells = "B17:C28,E17:G28,L17:O28," _
         & "BB17:BD28,BO17:BS28," _
         & "BY17:CB28,CG17:CI28,CS17:CW28"

      print SCells
```